# gke-1.13 and gke-1.14 differences in communication with Peered VPC

Tags: gke-networking

Does anyone know why GKE pod version 1.13 uses VM IP to communicate with Peered VPC where GKE pod version 1.14 and 1.15 uses just pod IP to communicate with peered VPC machine?

Answer (score 0):

[GCP release notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#changes_10) for Jun 4th 2019, says that :

> New clusters will begin to default to VPC-native

[VPC-native cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) says that there are 2 types of clusters. VPC-native and Routes-based ones.

> A cluster that uses alias IP ranges is called a VPC-native cluster. A cluster that uses Google Cloud Routes is called a routes-based cluster.

Additionally that page sheds light the default cluster network mode selection. It depends on the way the cluster is created.

The peculiarity is that you cannot convert a VPC-native cluster into a routes-based cluster, and you cannot convert a routes-based cluster into a VPC-native cluster.

Hope that is exactly the info you've been looking for.

Comment: HI @Nick 

I created both 1.13 and 1.14 pods cluster as VPC Native cluster but the difference I observed after VPC peering that after VPC both VPC Native cluster behave differently.

Comment: can you describe how exactly these clusters were created? I'd like to reproduce that, because google's documentation on topic doesn't left any ambiguity ( as far as understand the situation now)

Comment: Hi @Nick, 

I found another page  where people faced the same problem while upgarding from 1.13 to 1.14.  It seems like due to IP masq agent. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309735/vpn-access-to-in-house-network-not-working-after-gke-cluster-upgrade-to-1-14-6